# Sort the substrings of Timestamp column in azure data factory

Tags: sorting, azure-active-directory, timestamp, azure-data-factory, sink

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO5F8.png)My question is , I have a file in .txt format where there is a column called Timestamp along with many other columns.

Timestamp
01.06.2021 10:30:45...row 1
01.06.2021 10:40:45...row 2
01.06.2021 10:31:30...row 3

Now I would like to sort them in correct order, the required o/p would be:

Timestamp
01.06.2021 10:30:45....row 1
01.06.2021 10:31:30....row 2
01.06.2021 10:40:45....row 3

But the problem is I applied a data flow in ADF, with the sort activity but the files are not changing. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[this is how the Timestamp column looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO5F8.png)

Comment: Can you show use the file data more detailly, any screenshots?

Comment: @LeonYue, thanks for replying. I just added a link of the image that shows the Timestamp column structure . It takes the column as string. So, the problem is sorting is not happening at all.

Comment: Hi @chat_dev, got it! Did you try to convert the date format and then sort again?

Comment: Hi@LeonYue, yes I did that then the date section is going out of the picture. Keeping only the time stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the string `01.06.2021 10:30:45` is not a valied date string, that's why the sort doesn't work.

Please convert it to correct date data type with [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) and then sort again. For example:

**Source:**
[image]

**Derived Column**:  expression `toString(replace({Timestamp }, '.', '-'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss:sss')`:
[image]

**Sort active:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks@Leon Yeu. I agree with you. The dataset is quite unstructured and is coming in real time , with some other encoded format.I will try that right away and let you know. But thanks a lot for a quick solution.